# How to change divide to multiply in ARM machine code, in IDA？

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, ida

[image]

In Pseudocode line 198:
there is `/3`; I want to change it to `*3`

[image]
I find it in assembly language.

How to change it in IDA?

Comment: It's currently using a multiplicative inverse ([Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935)), so you have lots of space to work with for multiple instructions.  But of course ARM only needs one, `add dst, src, src lsl #1` to do `src + src*2`.  As far as how to actually use IDA's GUI to make that change, IDK.

Comment: Also, post code as text in code blocks, not pictures of code.